# javascript - check if either one sentence present in string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, include, search-multiple-words

I have a situation here ..

If there is a ,    var ttext = " enzo had a pen, watch and key "

i want to check if ttext has either pen or watch or key ..

i tried using include

```
var ttext = " enzo had a pen, watch and key "
let result = ttext.includes("pen");
```

how to check multiple items efficiently .. if includes  pen or watch or key .

Please help out.

var ttext = " enzo had a pen, watch and key "

let result = ttext.includes("pen");

want to check multiple words present

Comment: Using Regular Expressions (Regex) could help you with this. You should look into learning it

Comment: regular expression or an array of words with every() and do includes. Your solution will also match "open"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `or` operator to verify, like this:

`let result = ttext.includes("pen" || "watch" || "foo");`

Otherwise ff you want to check if all words are contained use `&&`:

`let result = ttext.includes("pen" && "watch" && "foo");`

Comment: Tried That , it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex for this: `/pen|watch|key/.test(ttext)`

Comment: let me test it out